# Junit 5 Launcher with jupiter-vintage-engine rule not honoring JUnit4 @ParametrizedTest

Tags: junit5, junit-vintage

I am working on porting a JUnit4 based test framework that uses JUnitCore to launch unit tests with JUnit5 launcher, junit-vintage-engine and a LauncherDiscoveryRequest with ClassSelector.

It is working for all cases except @ParameterizedTest.  Launcher is not honoring parameterized tests.

How do I get Launcher to honor JUnit4 parameterized tests?

I have tried adding     testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:${junit_jupiter_version}")

```
package ...;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

import ...TestCategory;
import ...TestType;
import ...DataScramblingRegexTest;

@TestType(...TestCategory.UNIT)
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class RegexGenTest {

    private static final int LOOKAROUND_ATTEMPTS = 100;

    @Parameterized.Parameter(0)
    public String regex;

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: RegexGenTest: {0}")
    public static Iterable<String[]> data() {
        return DataScramblingRegexTest.data();
    }

    @Test
    public void testTransformAndGenerate() {
        //even though Data Scramble Random Text doesn't transform every regex,
        //even if we do, and run it through Generex, it should still work.
        final String transformedRegex = RegexGen.transform(this.regex);
        String randomStr = RegexGen.generate(transformedRegex);
        if (RegexGen.containsLookArounds(this.regex)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < LOOKAROUND_ATTEMPTS; i++) {
                randomStr = RegexGen.generate(transformedRegex);
                if (randomStr.matches(this.regex)) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            Assert.fail("Lookaround failed");
        }
        Assert.assertTrue("generated string does not match regex: " + randomStr, randomStr.matches(this.regex));
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
    compile("junit:junit:${junit_version}")
    testCompile("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:${junit_jupiter_version}")
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junit_jupiter_version}")
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:${junit_jupiter_version}")
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junit_jupiter_version}")
```

where

```
junit_version=4.12
junit_jupiter_version=5.4.2
```

Note the proprietary `TestCategory.UNIT` annotation, we use this in our test discovery code and create a `Launcher` and a `LauncherdiscoveryRequest` with `ClassSelector`.

I expect JUnit 4 parameters to be supported by JUnit5 launcher with junit-jupiter-vintage engine and it is not supported.

Comment: Please complete your code example with the full test class including import statements and test methods. Your build file might also contain valuable information due to versions of included libraries.

Comment: @johanneslink just did. I removed just a bit of code that had company identification, but you can see the general idea.  There is an annotation that is read by the test framework to create a Launcher.

Comment: Update:  I converted the test to JUnit5 and the test framework still did not execute it with parameters. I then wrote a simple unit with Launcher running JUnit4 and JUnit5 parameterized tests and it worked fine.

There is something in my test framework that is disabling parameters.  Any ideas of where I should start looking?

Comment: The direct dependency on junit4 is probably unnecessary (comes transitively through vintage) and maybe harmful. Just a guess without possibility to try it.

Comment: I will try that.  Thanks.

I think I have found out what is going on.  Programmatically, I listen for events by using a TestExecutionListener and create TestSuite XML files.

Looks like for parameterized tests, there is only one event fired per test (and not one per parameter).  I need to look at the summary generating listener for that information.  Testing it.

Comment: Here is another curious side effect of parameterized tests.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319857/getting-the-values-of-parameters-for-parameterizedtests-in-testexecutionlistener