# Getting the values of parameters for ParameterizedTests in TestExecutionListener

Tags: junit5

In my test framework, I have to manually generate the TestSuite.xml.  In Junit4, the "Description" object passed by the listener contains the value of the parameters passed in a parameterized test, so the XML looks like this.

```
<testcase
  11     classname="com.workday.scramble.datagen.generator.regex.generator.RegexGenTest"
  12     name="testTransformAndGenerate[77: RegexGenTest: [0-9]{1,28}]"
  13     time="9.1E-4"/>
  14   <testcase
  15     classname="com.workday.scramble.datagen.generator.regex.generator.RegexGenTest"
  16     name="testTransformAndGenerate[123: RegexGenTest: [A-Za-z0-9 -]{1,64}]"
  17     time="0.0020299999999999997"/>
  18   <testcase
  19     classname="com.workday.scramble.datagen.generator.regex.generator.RegexGenTest"
  20     name="testTransformAndGenerate[112: RegexGenTest: [A-Za-z0-9 -]{1,31}]"
  21     time="0.00171"/>
  22   <testcase
  23     classname="com.workday.scramble.datagen.generator.regex.generator.RegexGenTest"
  24     name="testTransformAndGenerate[318: RegexGenTest: \d{37}]"
  25     time="7.3E-4"/>
```

In JUnit5, I use the `TestExecutionListener` callback and I get the method name like this:

```
    @Override
    public void executionFinished(final TestIdentifier testIdentifier, final TestExecutionResult testExecutionResult) {
        super.executionFinished(testIdentifier, testExecutionResult);
        logWithThrowable("Execution Finished: %s - %s - %s", testExecutionResult.getThrowable().orElse(null),
                testIdentifier.getDisplayName(), testIdentifier.getUniqueId(), testExecutionResult);
        final Optional<TestSource> source = testIdentifier.getSource();
        if (source.isPresent()) {
            final TestSource testSource = source.get();
            if (testSource instanceof ClassSource) {
               ...
            }
            else if (testSource instanceof MethodSource) {
                final MethodSource methodSource = (MethodSource) testSource;
                LOG.info("MethodSource: executionFinished for class: " + methodSource.getClassName() + " and method: "
                        + methodSource.getMethodName());
                final OmsTestMethod testMethod = getOmsTestMethod(methodSource);
                if (testMethod == null) {
                    return;
                }
                testMethod.setResult(testExecutionResult);
            }
        }
    }
```

This method name does not contain the parameters passed in, so the XML looks like this:

```
<testcase
 12     classname="com.workday.scramble.datagen.generator.regex.generator.RegexGenTest"
 13     name="testTransformAndGenerate"
 14     time="0.00366"/>
```

I treat the method names as unique, so there is only one entry.

TeamCity goes by the number of `testcase`s in the XML file, so the reporting is wrong.  `SummaryGeneratingListener` has the number of tests information, but I can't get TeamCity to use that.

Any idea of how to do this?

I have tried the various APIs in `MethodSource`.

```
    @Override
    public void executionFinished(final TestIdentifier testIdentifier, final TestExecutionResult testExecutionResult) {
        super.executionFinished(testIdentifier, testExecutionResult);
        logWithThrowable("Execution Finished: %s - %s - %s", testExecutionResult.getThrowable().orElse(null),
                testIdentifier.getDisplayName(), testIdentifier.getUniqueId(), testExecutionResult);
        final Optional<TestSource> source = testIdentifier.getSource();
        if (source.isPresent()) {
            final TestSource testSource = source.get();
            if (testSource instanceof ClassSource) {
               ...
            }
            else if (testSource instanceof MethodSource) {
                final MethodSource methodSource = (MethodSource) testSource;
                LOG.info("MethodSource: executionFinished for class: " + methodSource.getClassName() + " and method: "
                        + methodSource.getMethodName());
                final OmsTestMethod testMethod = getOmsTestMethod(methodSource);
                if (testMethod == null) {
                    return;
                }
                testMethod.setResult(testExecutionResult);
            }
        }
    }
```

I expect to see the method name contain the parameterized values as well so I can differentiate between various tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not customized the display name, the display name for a `@ParameterizedTest` should contain the arguments.

If that is not sufficient for you, feel free to raise an issue here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/new/choose

Comment: Yes, got it.  Thanks.  I used the display name.

Comment: Has by chance anything changed about this situation?